# How do I modify the FlowCover sample application to work horizontally?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

The [FlowCover](http://chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m) sample code provides an OpenGL ES implementation of the coverflow effect.

I would like to alter this in order to have it work horizontally, not vertically.  How would I go about modifying this sample to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to run in Portrait mode rather than landscape

In FlowCoverViewController.m, add Portrait orientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
            (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the grate reply it solved the orientation but the covers scrolling into horizontal but  i want to make this scrolling into vertical means top to bottom or bottom to top into portrait mode.Thank You. please reply.@Nick